# Is there a list of Windows special directories/shortcuts (like %TEMP%)?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, environment-variables, special-locations

I'm looking for a reference list of shortcuts like `%TEMP%`.

When I'm using <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or Windows Explorer and type `%temp%`, the Windows Explorer takes me to the Temp directory. Are there more of these shortcuts?

UPDATE:
[I found a helpful reference page for environment variables (might not be up-to-date with Windows 7)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120101144026/http://www.scriptlogic.com/support/CustomScripts/environmentVariableReference.html).

Comment: [Similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/217695/where-is-the-official-list-of-windows-environment-variables)

Comment: This should be community-wiki since it’s too general a question with no actual answer (it’s definitely a discussion question).

Comment: The question is quite straight forward, I need a list of environment variables (which is a fixed list) and is answered by Dennis Williamson.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but the link posted under the heading `UPDATE:` is no longer active.

Comment: Could this question be answered by someone, please?  The answers below are mildly interested, but are not a list of OS-defined aliases (e.g., %appdata%, %localappdata%).  We have one response which lists binaries in windows, one response that points to the environment variable setting (which is not a type of alias, although an environment variable can redefine an alias), and one response that points to control panels, and a lot of outdated links to documentation for old versions of Windows, but nobody has answered this bit of Windows arcana.

Comment: I would just correct that what the OP is asking about are **not** any special directories or shortcuts but regular **environment variables**. They may contain any numeric or alphanumeric value, some of them just contain filesystem paths.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

There are 156 run commands at [mypchell.com](http://mypchell.com/guides/34-guides/69-156-useful-run-commands).
Here is a more complete list including the [Windows Environment Commands](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) (e.g. %temp%, %HomeDrive%, etc)

### Windows Environment Path Variables

**%AllUsersProfile%** - Open the All User's Profile `C:\ProgramData`
**%AppData%** - Opens AppData folder `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming`
**%CommonProgramFiles%** - `C:\Program Files\Common Files`
**%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%** - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files`
**%HomeDrive%** - Opens your home drive `C:\`
**%LocalAppData%** - Opens local AppData folder `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local`
**%ProgramData%** - `C:\ProgramData`
**%ProgramFiles%** -  `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`
**%ProgramFiles(x86)%** - `C:\Program Files (x86)`
**%Public%** - `C:\Users\Public`
**%SystemDrive%** - `C:`
**%SystemRoot%** - Opens Windows folder `C:\Windows`
**%Temp%** - Opens temporary file Folder `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp`
**%UserProfile%** - Opens your user's profile `C:\Users\{username}`
**%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup** - Opens Windows 10 Startup location for program shortcuts

---

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

### Run commands

**Calc** - Calculator
**Cfgwiz32** - ISDN Configuration Wizard
**Charmap** - Character Map
**Chkdisk** - Repair damaged files
**Cleanmgr** - Cleans up hard drives
**Clipbrd** - Windows Clipboard viewer
**Cmd** - Opens a new Command Window (cmd.exe)
**Control** - Displays Control Panel
**Dcomcnfg** - DCOM user security
**Debug** - Assembly language programming tool
**Defrag** - Defragmentation tool
**Drwatson** - Records programs crash & snapshots
**Dxdiag** - DirectX Diagnostic Utility
**Explorer** - Windows Explorer
**Fontview** - Graphical font viewer
**Ftp** - ftp.exe program
**Hostname** - Returns Computer's name
**Ipconfig** - Displays IP configuration for all network adapters
**Jview** - Microsoft Command-line Loader for Java classes
**MMC** - Microsoft Management Console
**Msconfig** - Configuration to edit startup files
**Msinfo32** - Microsoft System Information Utility
**Nbtstat** - Displays stats and current connections using NetBios over TCP/IP
**Netstat** - Displays all active network connections
**Nslookup** - Returns your local DNS server
**Odbcad32** - ODBC Data Source Administrator
**Ping** - Sends data to a specified host/IP
**Regedit** - registry Editor
**Regsvr32** - register/de-register DLL/OCX/ActiveX
**Regwiz** - Registration wizard
**Sfc /scannow** - System File Checker
**Sndrec32** - Sound Recorder
**Sndvol32** - Volume control for soundcard
**Sysedit** - Edit system startup files (config.sys, autoexec.bat, win.ini, etc.)
**Systeminfo** - display various system information in text console
**Taskmgr** - Task manager
**Telnet** - Telnet program
**Taskkill** - kill processes using command line interface
**Tskill** - reduced version of Taskkill from Windows XP Home
**Tracert** - Traces and displays all paths required to reach an internet host
**Winchat** - simple chat program for Windows networks
**Winipcfg** - Displays IP configuration

#### Microsoft Office suite

**winword** - Microsoft Word
**excel** - Microsoft Excel
**powerpnt** - Microsoft PowerPoint
**msaccess** - Microsoft Access
**outlook** - Microsoft Outlook
**ois** - Microsoft Picture Manager
**winproj** - Microsoft Project

#### Management Consoles

**certmgr.msc** - Certificate Manager
**ciadv.msc** - Indexing Service
**compmgmt.msc** - Computer management
**devmgmt.msc** - Device Manager
**dfrg.msc** - Defragment
**diskmgmt.msc** - Disk Management
**fsmgmt.msc** - Folder Sharing Management
**eventvwr.msc** - Event Viewer
**gpedit.msc** - Group Policy (< XP Pro)
**iis.msc** - Internet Information Services
**lusrmgr.msc** - Local Users and Groups
**mscorcfg.msc** - Net configurations
**ntmsmgr.msc** - Removable Storage
**perfmon.msc** - Performance Manager
**secpol.msc** - Local Security Policy
**services.msc** - System Services
**wmimgmt.msc** - Windows Management

#### Control Panel utilities

**access.cpl** - Accessibility Options
**hdwwiz.cpl** - Add New Hardware Wizard
**appwiz.cpl** - Add/Remove Programs
**timedate.cpl** - Date and Time Properties
**desk.cpl** - Display Properties
**inetcpl.cpl** - Internet Properties
**joy.cpl** - Joystick Properties
**main.cpl keyboard** - Keyboard Properties
**main.cpl** - Mouse Properties
**ncpa.cpl** - Network Connections
**ncpl.cpl** - Network Properties
**telephon.cpl** - Phone and Modem options
**powercfg.cpl** - Power Management
**intl.cpl** - Regional settings
**mmsys.cpl sounds** - Sound Properties
**mmsys.cpl** - Sounds and Audio Device Properties
**sysdm.cpl** - System Properties
**nusrmgr.cpl** - User settings
**firewall.cpl** - Firewall Settings (sp2)
**wscui.cpl** - Security Center (sp2)
**Wupdmgr** - Takes you to Microsoft Windows Update

Thanks to The New Tech for the original forum posting.

Comment: @ troynt + Gabriel: http://blogs.vmware.com/thinapp/2012/05/macro-folder-locations-and-newer-versions-of-windows.html

Comment: i dont see program~1 either

Comment: Check out: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html

Comment: netplwiz is missing (needed to e.g. configure automatic sign-in)

Comment: You can also use `shell:startup` in Windows Explorer or Run to get to the Start menu's startup folder (tested on Windows 11).

Comment: also for missing `LocalLow` shortcut just use `%LocalAppData%Low`

Answer (score 56):

Open a CMD prompt and type this in to see a complete list of the environmental variables (eg. %TEMP%) on your system:

```
set
```

You can also use [this list](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-shell-keyword.html) to open special locations in Explorer, using the Start Menu search box.

Comment: Use `dir env:` to do the same in PowerShell. (PowerShell treats the environment, registry, ... rather like more (disk) drives.)

Comment: Give a man a fish, feed him for a day, teach him how to fish, feed him until he upgrades to a new OS.

Comment: For a _complete_ list in NT you should add some more to what's returned by `set`. Think of `%time%`, `%cd%`, `%random%`... Some more undocumented variables: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,33812,00.asp

Answer (score 29):

Also if you're interested in Windows Vista or Windows 7 shortcuts then there's also the 'Godmode' folders.

**The “Monster” Control Panel**

The godmode will enable the “Monster control panel” that includes all functions and is quite large. See below for specific codes to create specific links.

1. Create a new folder (right-click and click on “New Folder”). Right-click on the folder and click on rename, copy and paste this:

> GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}

2. This folder will now be a shortcut to the Windows 7 godmode. The godmode allows you to quickly access many Windows 7 functions via a GUI.

#### Specific Godmode Codes

There are other codes for specific features and functions. The “monster control panel” above will give you the complete list of all features at once, but that list is quite lengthy so you might want to create multiple, smaller and specific links:

Important: To use the codes below you don't have to use the word “Godmode”. It can be anything you like.

Example: `Foobar.{00C6D95F-329C-409a-81D7-C46C66EA7F33}`

**Control panel features Code**

```
Enter a default location.{00C6D95F-329C-409a-81D7-C46C66EA7F33}
Use biometric devices with Windows.{0142e4d0-fb7a-11dc-ba4a-000ffe7ab428}
Select a power plan.{025A5937-A6BE-4686-A844-36FE4BEC8B6D}
Select which icons and notifications appear on taskbar.{05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}
Store credentials for automatic logon.{1206F5F1-0569-412C-8FEC-3204630DFB70}
Install a program from the network.{15eae92e-f17a-4431-9f28-805e482dafd4}
Choose the programs that Windows uses by default.{17cd9488-1228-4b2f-88ce-4298e93e0966}
Assembly Cache Viewer.{1D2680C9-0E2A-469d-B787-065558BC7D43}
Manage wireless networks.{1FA9085F-25A2-489B-85D4-86326EEDCD87}
Network.{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}
Computer.{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
Devices and Printers.{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}
RemoteApp and Desktop Connections.{241D7C96-F8BF-4F85-B01F-E2B043341A4B}
Windows Firewall.{4026492F-2F69-46B8-B9BF-5654FC07E423}
Windows Explorer.{62D8ED13-C9D0-4CE8-A914-47DD628FB1B0}
System.{78F3955E-3B90-4184-BD14-5397C15F1EFC}
```

Read more: http://windows7themes.net/windows-7-enable-secret-godmode.html#ixzz16x8qbk8b

Comment: Interresting! Will be looking into this soon

Comment: There's nothing special about the string "Godmode"; it can be any name you like, so long as it is followed by a period and then the value in curly braces.

Comment: This is a bit of infrastructure in windows that was intended for the system itself. This expanded listing allows helps the start menu search find items on the control panel. There is nothing here that cannot be reached by more conventional means. But it is kind of neat.

Comment: With Windows 10, GodMode was changed to `JeezMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`

Comment: @SilapAliyev a little late to the party for that joke. See phogg's comment above.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a complete answer but I just wanted to mention a shortcut I didn't see on any of the links mentioned in the other answers.

Typing `startup` in the address bar of File Explorer redirects to the Startup Programs folder i.e. to

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Similarly, typing `start menu` redirects to

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
```

I mainly use the first one more frequently.

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: Under Windows 11: `startup` opens the Webbrowser on URL `startup/`. `start menu` also opens the Webbrowser but fires up Bing search engine to look for `start menu`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the link to official documentation for [Recognized Environment Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables)

Here is the link to the [respective markdown file](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-itpro-docs/blob/public/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables.md) in GitHub.