# Where is the Official list of Windows Environment Variables?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, documentation

I'm working on some `.bat` stuff created in a legacy application, which uses many environment variables. I need to know exactly what is every one of them (`%windir%`, `%os%`, etc.).

So I need the **official** Microsoft Documentation about the System Environment Variables of Windows (at least from the NT version).

I've reading some sites with partial information (there are variables absent, such as `%os%`), so I really want to look at the Official info.

Searching with Google, Bing and inside the MSDN site give just reports about one or other variable, but no a comprehensive and centralized list of all.

Anybody knows where is that documentation available?

Comment: I would say there isn't one; any app can use any variables it likes.

Comment: @Néstor: Simply typing `set` in a command prompt lists quite a few, including all you mentioned.  
They all seem fairly easy to understand.

Comment: http://www.scriptlogic.com/support/CustomScripts/environmentVariableReference.html

Comment: Updated my answer to include a link too.

Comment: +1 @moab - Posted the same link without noticing. Got it from Wikipedia?

Comment: [Similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/217504/list-of-windows-special-directories-shortcuts-like-temp)

Comment: @Brian, no, my best friend Google SSL found that link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of Windows special directories/shortcuts (like %TEMP%)?](https://superuser.com/a/1704679/863212)

Answer (score 4):

While not official the best *functional* reference I've seen, that has been reliable and kept up to date for many years, is **SS64** http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html. It includes undocumented variables and OS version specific info.

Answer (score 3):

Site? <strike>Maybe not?</strike> Try this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20101129130948/http://www.scriptlogic.com/support/CustomScripts/environmentVariableReference.html). The list even breaks it down to what OS can use it. The variable will look a little different. That is only because it is missing the percent signs that are at the beginning and end.

Still not happy? Try this opening *Command Prompt* and type `set` and hit enter. It will list all the variables. As with the site listed above, the variable here will also look a little different.

Comment: That site doesn't seem to exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

No complete list either but this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110205060220/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190899) may already help to detect the OS you have.

Typing set in cmd.exe for getting a list of all really used variables on your system is known I assume?!