# Environment Variables for Windows' Built-in Libraries?

Tags: windows-7, windows, environment-variables, libraries

Does Windows 7 define environment variables for pre-existing Libraries? I am curious because I often use these when typing a path in Open/Save dialogs or from the `Run` prompt. For example, to get to the current user's Firefox settings directory, `run`:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox
```

It's a handy shortcut, and I was hoping to find something similar for library paths. For example:

```
%LIBRARIES%\Music\
%MUSIC%\
```

I understand that libraries aggregate one-or-more top-level folders, so there could be ambiguity. Microsoft has a [list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_2) of environment variables, but most are not accessible via the Windows UI. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/217695/where-is-the-official-list-of-windows-environment-variables) also links to a nice list, but does not include a user's `Documents` folder, `Music` folder, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Libraries are in fact just `xml` files which define how to display a collection of folders. They are displayed using a special shell extension which is built in to Windows. Since they are not real folders, files and sub-folders cannot be accessed directly via a path.

With an *open* explorer window, you can type in the address bar:

```
libraries\music
```

This does *not* seem to work from the `File Name` box of open/save dialogs. Nor does it work with the `run` command.

**What you can do about it:**

Windows Vista introduced the "[Known Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911%28VS.85%29.aspx)" concept. It replaces the older "constant special item ID list" ([CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) methodology used in XP. There is an [excellent post](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/04/14/libraries-under-the-hood.aspx) on the Windows Blog; it discusses this change and provides an overview of the `*.library-ms` file structure.

Known Folders have GUIDs. To access them via command line, prefix your URI with `knownfolder:`. There are [dozens defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584%28VS.85%29.aspx). To access the current user's `Music` folder for example, `run` the following command:

```
knownfolder:{4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43}
```

This will get you to the pre-defined *default* music folder. So, if you have changed the library's folder, this will unfortunately not work.

A library's default folder can be [accessed](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/www7.aspx#2) programmatically by using [IShellLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, but that is out of the scope of my original question. It seems that the best approach is to either:

1. Manually map enviroment variables to their known path
2. Or manually map environment variables using their GUID. The advantage here is that you make it a system variable and have it work for all users).

Answer (score 5):

If you want `%music%` to point to your music folder then you just add a new environmental variable to your system.

[image]

If you want to `%Libraries%` point to your libraries then make a shortcut on `c:\`, for example, and then create a new environmental variable pointing to your `c:\libraries` shortcut. (but entering directly into sub-folders will not work, but you can create a new variable for those that are in Libraries)

You can then call them both from run with `%music%` or `%Libraries%`

Comment: Indeed, this is probably the best workaround. I went ahead and defined `%MUSIC%`, as that is what piqued my interest. Still, I find the lack of variables odd. There doesn't even seem to be `%DOCUMENTS%`