# Do Windows libraries have an environment variable?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, symbolic-link

**Goal:**

I'd like to save files without breaking my save settings if the drive letter changes.

---

**Example:**
This works using [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) and [changing the location setting of my user library folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxJ3G.png):

```
%USERPROFILE%\Videos\YouTube\GrumpyCat_00.mp4
```

The path above will work no matter the drive letter.

---

**Problem:**

I've saved videos files across multiple locations and grouped them into a *Videos library*; so, I'm not able to use the `%USERPROFILE%\Videos` directory format.

---

**Question:**

Can I use a Library environment variable to save to any folder grouped into that library?

---

**Alternate Consideration:**

I've considered using *symbolic links* inside the Videos folder as an alternative to grouping the videos into a library.

Once I own a media server I think I can use a server directory as the location for (in this instance) Videos and always save using `%USERPROFILE%\Videos\(Folder Name)` - instead of saving media files on my main computer and trying to consolidate and organize later.

Comment: you can create your own environment variables

Comment: I'm not certain how to do that.

I went to the set a new environment variable. (I used System Variable instead of user...). I named the variable VIDEOLIBRARY - and gave it the value of "Libraries\Videos" - but that didn't work...

Comment: "Libraries\Videos" is not a valid path to a folder. some more info: https://superuser.com/questions/240942/environment-variables-for-windows-7-built-in-libraries?rq=1

Comment: That was excellent information; thanks! I searched the registry and found the ID of the folder. I can open it in the address bar with knownfolder:{491E922F-5643-4af4-A7EB-4E7A138D8174} -- but, after changing the variable value, I'm still unable to use %VIDEOLIBRARY% for the same effect

Comment: Okay, I think I just needed to refresh Windows explorer. Now it's working :)