# How do I delete saved data from a specific flash game

Tags: windows, google-chrome, flash

I've been playing a flash game where you upgrade your character throughout the game, but now I'd like to start over from the beginning and upgrade everything again. I've tried going to where all my sol files are located deep in the Flash Player appdata, but I have no way of locating the specific game.

I also tried going to [Macromedia's support page](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html), but the problem is it only lets me delete flash cookies from an entire site as far as I can tell, which I don't want because I have saved data from other games on the same site which I want to keep.

I just want to remove the data from this one game. Is there any way to go about locating the right file to delete?

Comment: If the flash game is not on your computer, and is hosted on an online website, then you cannot reset your game data, because the data is on the website, secured and available to you only via login for the game. If you could post a link to the game (web-address), then maybe the game-data from the website be retrieved via `source` of the game page.

Comment: But if I play the game on another browser it starts from scratch, so it's definitely stored in my browser in some way. It's not a multiplier online game or anything where the data is stored somewhere online. It doesn't require logging in either.

Comment: What browser are you using? Maybe there are some flashvars or something for the flash file, you'll have to check out the source of the page for flashvars, if you cannot share the game url here.... In the flashvars, see if there's any name of game-data file that could be found on your C Drive of windows.

Comment: Or the game/site is using a cookie to track when you access the site.  Could you post a link the game?  as mk117 suggested.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, because I have no flash app/game to test this with, but what I'd do is this: Right click inside flash, go to settings. Go to the folder icon with the arrow. Slide the slider all the way to the left (use no storage) then okay. Reload the page, Go back to this slider, and set it back to the middle, then reload again.

Comment: I'm using chrome. The link to the game is: http://www.wixgames.co.uk/game.asp?id=31. The sidebar thing removes the data from every game on the site. I was able to do that with the other link I provided in my original post.

Comment: If you clear you cookies and/or you browser history you should reset your game state.

Answer (score 2):

Locally shared objects (LSOs) or "Flash cookies" are how Flash stores information on your computer between sessions; this includes Flash game save files.

From [ActionScript 3.0 Developer’s Guide / Files and data / Storing local data / Shared objects](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d80.html):

> When... a shared object [is created], Flash Player creates a new directory for the application and domain inside its sandbox. It also creates a *.sol file that stores the SharedObject data. The default location of this file is a subdirectory of the user’s home directory. The following table shows the default locations of this directory:
>
> - Windows 95/98/ME/2000/XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects`
> - Windows Vista/Windows 7: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects`
> - Macintosh OS X: `/Users/username/Library/Preferences/Macromedia/Flash Player/#SharedObjects/web_domain/path_to_application/application_name/object_name.sol`
> - Linux/Unix: `/home/username/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects/web_domain/path_to_application/application_name/object_name.sol`
>
> Below the #SharedObjects directory is a randomly-named directory. Below that is a directory that matches the hostname, then the path to the application, and finally the *.sol file.

In Windows, you can take advantage of [Windows environment path variables](https://superuser.com/questions/217504/is-there-a-list-of-windows-special-directories-shortcuts-like-temp) for an easy-to-copy link for everything but the random bit: `%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\`

For most gaming websites, the cookies will be in a subfolder specific to the game within the url folder. In the case of the question, the save would be in: `www.wixgames.co.uk\swf\rocketbootsinc.swf\`