# Cannot use command promt

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, jdk

Mt command prompt will not run any default windows commands because I changed my PATH to jdk (Java Development Kit). Is there a way to fix this without changing the PATH back? If there isn't what should the default PATH be?

Answer (score 0):

Change back to the original PATH and just append the Java directory path to it. To concatenate an additional directory, just append semicolon followed by the full directory path.

In most versions of Windows, there are two [Windows PATHs](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm): System and User. You can add a folder to either, without removing others (unless the length gets too great... in which case, use [path shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/217504/is-there-a-list-of-windows-special-directories-shortcuts-like-temp), such as `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` to replace `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and you can create your own path shortcuts, too). Java probably should be added to the System PATH, but if it's too long, you can try adding it

Note that it may be easier [to edit the PATH system variable using PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) than with the Control Panel applet.